# MySQL FIND_IN_SET search result needed in original sequence

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I am using `FIND_IN_SET` in MySQL as below :

```
SELECT  
        color, b.id
FROM    cards b
        where FIND_IN_SET(b.color, 'gold,gold,bronze,silver,silver') > 0
GROUP   BY b.id
        ORDER BY RAND() 
        limit 5;
```

And I get output as below :

[image]

However, I want to get cards in the same sequence as in the parameter string supplied to `FIND_IN_SET` i.e.

```
gold, gold, bronze, silver, silver
```

So the first output row should be of gold color, then another gold, then bronze and so on - in the same sequence without any random search.

I cannot have self join as it's a big table.

Comment: Without any random search .. but you're using `ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: there are thousands of gold, silver, bronze cards & i need to select random cards of those color.

Comment: I'm guessing that this operation will output into an app?

Comment: yes.. it goes into the app - but need to do it in sql query itself

Comment: How do you determine how many values and what values to inpunt in `FIND_IN_SET`? Also, where does it come from? User input?

Comment: it comes from a variable $pack_sql_comma_separated and this variable would have value like 'gold,silver,gold,gold,silver,gold' or any such combination.

Comment: Why do you have to do this in the query? Sorting in your app would be easier

Comment: Are you using PHP?

Comment: Yes. I am using php.

Comment: I actually would need to use FIND_IN_SET in reverse way I guess ( which won't work ). I need to get row from the table for every element in my comma separated list.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this using a `UNION` of 3 queries to find random 'gold', 'silver' and 'bronze' medallists, and then order those results using [`FIELD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT color, id
FROM (
    (
        SELECT color, id
        FROM cards
        WHERE color = 'gold'
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 2
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT color, id
        FROM cards
        WHERE color = 'bronze'
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT color, id
        FROM cards
        WHERE color = 'silver'
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 2
    )
) m
ORDER BY FIELD(color, 'gold', 'bronze', 'silver')
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66175/4)

Here's a way you might implement this as a combination of PHP/MySQL:

```
$pack_sql_comma_separated = 'gold,silver,gold,gold,silver,gold';
$colors = explode(',', $pack_sql_comma_separated);
$counts = array_count_values($colors);
$sql = "SELECT color, id FROM (";
$subqueries = [];
foreach ($counts as $color => $count) {
    $subqueries[] = "(
        SELECT color, id
        FROM cards
        WHERE color = '$color'
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT $count
    )";
}
$sql .= implode(' UNION ALL ', $subqueries) . ') m';
// run SQL query
// ...
// assume all query results read into $rows according to medal colour, something like this
$rows = array('gold' => array(array('id' => 20),
                              array('id' => 5),
                              array('id' => 4),
                              array('id' => 27)
                              ),
              'silver' => array(array('id' => 19),
                                array('id' => 11)
                                )
             );

//display in required order
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    $card = array_shift($rows[$color]);
    echo "$color {$card['id']}\n";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vHCY8)

Comment: the sequcne would change gold, bronze, silver and it has 12 such colors in any random order...

Comment: @rohankoshti I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: in your answer gold is limited to 2 - but there can be different sets which will have gold as 5, gold as 9, broze as 4, bronze as 8, etc. Its not fixed. Plus there are 12 different colors like gold and silver.

Comment: OK, I see. You would need to modify the query for each of those situations (just as you would your original query).

Comment: You could simply use parameters for each of the colours and the number of each that you want, although if you want more or less than 3 you would need to modify the query to add/remove a select from the `UNION` and the call to `FIELD`

Comment: @rohankoshti please see my edit, I've added some sample PHP code for how you might make this query work.

Comment: @rohankoshti Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: I did something similar but totally in mysql. Created a temp table with all different colors and count for each of them, Then did a simple query with for each color to select specific number of random records needed.